# Vizdoom and gymnasium multiple enviroments

Tags: python, python-3.x, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I'm using gymnasium with Vizdoom, trying to apply the A2C algorithm with stable baselines. I know gymnasium supports multiple enviroments [(Example here)](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/a2c.html) but I was wondering if it's possible to do with a third party enviroment. If it's possible, anyone knows how to do it?